# Responsive design 3 columns to 1?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I wanted to ask – if I have 3 columns of DIVs that I want to responsively change to 2 and 1 depending on the width of the user's screen (1 column for mobile devices) – what's the best way to do it? The `div` elements should simply stack under each other.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">  
        <!--left-->
        <div class="col1">  
        </div>
        <!--/left-->

        <!--center-->
        <div class="col2">
        </div>
        <!--/center-->

        <!--right-->
        <div class="col3">
        </div>
        <!--/right-->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Thank you!

PS My design looks like this:

[image]

To

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can accomplish this with the `float` property. You'll just need to clear the floats by adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent or using a clearfix:

[**FLOAT EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jwhtvL/)

**CSS**

```
.row{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col{
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

## **OR**

You can use `display: inline-block;` to do the same

```
.col{
   background: red;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 5px 2px;
}
```

[**INLINE-BLOCK EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jwhtvL/2/)